# Best practice for using PHP DB to populate JQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

For my site, I have a list of cities in the U.S. (about 30,000) and I'm using that to autocomplete a freeform field, so users can start typing their city, and choose it from the list.

My question is, what is the best way to put the data into the autocomplete list?

1. Read all of the data from the DB via PHP, and put it into a large Javascript array.
2. Make a call to the DB every time the user updates the city field, and search for cities that match what they're typing.

I ask this because I'd like to know which is best for performance.  It seems like #2 would have a lot of DB calls, and overhead if 100+ people are hitting the site at a time.

#1 may not be great becuase 30,000 elements in an array seems like a lot.

I'm currently using method #1 and it seems OK, but it does look kind of sloppy when you view the source code and it shows 30,000 lines for the array.

Any suggestions/Input is appreciated.

Comment: As an FYI, in the end I went with #2.  I tested both, and performance from a PC was fine for each, but when testing from a tablet or cell phone, the first solution was very slow to autocomplete.  The second solution was almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions seems to be expensive for performance. The first one may cause problems with slow computers while the second one is expensive for the server resources.

I would suggest you to use a full-text search engine like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) because it supports complex search queries and is really much faster than DB thanks to caching.

Answer (score 1):

I do always use #2

This is what my PHP can look like:

**PHP**

```
//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

//Prepare Query
for($i=1; $i<=strlen($term); $i++) {
    $test_term = substr($term, 0, $i);
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT column as value FROM table WHERE column LIKE '".$test_term."%'";
}
```